# ERROR 17058 COULD NOT FIND THE ERROR LOG

Tags: sql-server

We just installed SQL Server on 1st node of windows cluster and it stop/start fine from configuration manager but from command line it is giving error and I checked that service account have all the rights on the folder, any idea how to fix the issue since we need to some tasks and I need to start SQL Server in single user mode from command line (registry entry looks fine):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn>sqlservr.exe
2013-02-22 17:27:39.68 Server      Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-22 17:27:39.68 Server      initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
 Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2013-02-22 17:27:39.99 Server      Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-22 17:27:39.99 Server      initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
 Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2013-02-22 17:27:40.30 Server      Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-22 17:27:40.30 Server      initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
 Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2013-02-22 17:27:40.62 Server      Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-22 17:27:40.62 Server      initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
 Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2013-02-22 17:27:40.93 Server      Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-22 17:27:40.93 Server      initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
 Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
2013-02-22 17:27:41.24 Server      Error: 17058, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2013-02-22 17:27:41.24 Server      initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''.
 Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

Comment: Have you verified the path for the error log?  You can find it using the [steps outlined here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2506/identify-location-of-the-sql-server-error-log-file/).

Comment: Is SQL Server clustered? If so, why are you attempting to start a clustered instance from the command line? And is this the currently active node?

Comment: What switches are you passing? You'll need to pass in -c and probably -s.

Comment: Sounds like you are perhaps attempting to start the service on a non-active node.  This would be one possible reason for this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Event Viewer error message:

```
Event ID 17058
initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''
```

I did solve this "initialize error log" (initerrlog) problem.

I eventually discovered that when viewed through "Sql Server Configuration Manager", a semi-colon `;` must be present between each parameter in the string.   (Caveat: This might not apply to newer versions of Configuration Manger; newer versions might show each parameter as a separate string on its own row.) This use of semicolon is counter-intuitive for me, since the string looks like a command line, where-in such semicolons would prematurely terminate the command; but here, the semicolon is used to terminate parameters (not the command).  Furthermore, everything other than semicolon is taken as a literal.  Therefore, do not use quotes to surround the path or file name, because the quote characters are taken literally.  Blank spaces are not separators; they are literals; only semi-colons are separators.  Don't put a blank space between flag and param, where `-d` etc is what I mean by flags.  So, the string should be something like:

```
-dD:\SQL-Data\master.mdf; -lE:\SQL-Logs\mastlog.ldf; -eE:\SQL-Errs\ErrorLog.txt
```

As an alternative to Configuration Manager, one can use `regedit` and create separate params `SQLArg0`, `SQLArg1`, `SQLArg2`.  Each is a String Value, and each gets just one of the params.  Each such String Value starts with the flag, like `-d`.  Do not include semi-colon.  To find the place where these params go, look for a registry entry that resembles the following:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\Parameters\SQLArg1  (or something similar)
```

If you do the work within `regedit` and then you go back and shut-down and restart the Configuration Manager, you will see that Configuration Manager has concatenated the parameters, with semi-colons as separators. (As mentioned earlier, this observation is applicable to older versions of SQL Server Configuration Manager).